# Using backspace to move back to previous textBox (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, events

This may be a simple question. I'm new to C# (and most programming) and I am trying to make a program that consists of two text boxes. The information in these textboxes will frequently be deleted and new information will need entered, so it needs to be quick. For convenience I'm trying to make the backspace key refocus on the previous textbox rather than using Shift+Space or clicking. Here is what I have. The program runs, but the code below doesn't seem to do what I intend it to do.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && textBox2.TextLength == 0)
  textBox1.Focus();
```

So, when textbox2 has 0 characters and backspace is subsequently keyed, I would like it to move back to textbox1. Thanks for any help.

Comment: And when is this code being run?

Comment: As @Yahya pointed, in which event you do that? Also what is *intended* from that code to do, but is not happening? I would do it with `TextChanged` and will only check for `textBox2.Text.Length == 0`. This would move focus to `textBox1` in any case when `textBox2` content is *changed* and *become empty* (Backspace, Selecting all and deleting, etc).

Comment: I'm doing this in KeyUp, but have tried TextChanged. If I only use use the textBox2.Text.Length == 0 under TextChanged, hitting backspace one time causes the text length to reach zero and the cursor immediately goes to textBox1. This is a pain if you need to delete 1 character in textBox2 and reenter it. It requires you to hit tab to move back to textBox2 again. If there is 1 character in textBox2, I am essentially trying to make it move back to textBox1 upon pressing backspace twice. The first clears the field and the second moves the cursor to the textBox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get it to work finally. What I did wasn't too different than what I was trying before, but here is how I did it.

1. I created two text boxes from the .cs [Design] view.
2. I selected each box and clicked the "Events" lightning bolt icon under Properties. This is something I left out previously when this didn't work.
3. I set both of them to KeyPress and TextChanged (i.e. textBox1_KeyPress & textBox1_TextChanged (Did the same thing with textBox2). I don't know if this is part of the reason why it worked. I'm just documenting my actions.
4. I double clicked each textBox, which created an EventArgs for each. This is where I stored my regular code.
5. In addition to the EventArgs I manually created a KeyEventArgs (see below) where I put the function for the Backspace. Here is the code:

> ```
> // Here is the KeyEventArgs I created using KeyPress (Public).
> ```
>
> public void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>
> ```
>        {
>
>            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
>                textBox1.Focus();
>        }
>
>
> // Here is where the rest of my code (Private).
> ```
>
> private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> ```
>            {
>            if (textBox2.Text == "A")
>                richTextBox3.Text = "January";
>
>            if (textBox2.Text == "B")
>                richTextBox3.Text = "February";
>
>            if (textBox2.Text == "C")
>                richTextBox3.Text = "March";
>
> // Code Continues...
> ```

Sorry if this isn't clear. I just wanted to document what I did in case it helps someone later. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You should either edit your original question to add extra information, or use comments to discuss small points with people. Please do not use an answer if you are not answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

So to make this work you're going to need to make sure you run this code on `KeyUp`, but you also do not need multiple `KeyUp` handlers to do this. Consider this `KeyUp` handler:

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null) { return; }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        // this here of course being the Form
        // Select causes the form to select the previous control in the tab order
        this.Select(true, false);
    }
}
```

Now just attach this handler to **all** text boxes that you want to behave this way and they'll all work.

Comment: This is not working for me yet. Is it a problem to simultaneously & separately have EventArgs and KeyEventArgs at the same time for a single textBox?

Comment: @user3620471: Don't double-click on the text box from the designer. Click on the control, press F4, go to the Events tab, and double-click on the `KeyUp` event.